# Simple example of non-integrable holomorphic connection

Tags: complex-geometry, connections

Let $X$ be a complex manifold with complex dimension $d$ and structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$. Let $E$ be a locally free sheaf on $X$. A $holomorphic$ connection on $E$ is a morphism of sheaves
 $$\nabla: E \to E \text{ }\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X} \Omega_{X}^{1} $$ satisfying the product rule $\nabla(fs) = s \otimes df + f\nabla(s)$ for all open $U \subset X$ with $f \in \mathcal{O}_X(U), s \in E(U)$ . The connection $\nabla$ is said to be $flat$ or $integrable$ if the composite $$ E \xrightarrow{\nabla} E \text{ } \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X} \Omega_{X}^{1} \xrightarrow{\nabla_1}  E \text{ } \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X} \Omega_{X}^{2}$$ is $0$  where $\nabla_1$ is the map to 2-forms $s \otimes w \mapsto \nabla(s) \wedge w \text{ } +  s \otimes dw$. What is a simple example of a triple $(X, E, \nabla)$ with $\nabla$ non-integrable? Any such example must necessarily have $d \geq 2$.

Comment: The examples should come from non-cpt complex mfds.

Comment: Crossposted to MO [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/360581/simple-example-of-non-integrable-holomorphic-connection)

Answer (score 0):

Any degree *nonzero* line bundle on a compact Riemann surface has a non-integrable holomorphic connection. The reason is that its *first Chern class* is nonzero.

More precisely, take a compact Riemann surface $X$, and a line bundle together with Hermitian metric $(\mathcal{L},h)$ on $X$, then the curvature form is $$\Omega=-\partial\bar{\partial}\log h$$
 This curvature form $\Omega$ is exactly the composite $\nabla_1\circ\nabla$, where $\nabla$ is the Chern connection associated to $h$. (You can read more on Griffiths & Harris's Principles of Algebraic Geometry, Chapter 0, section 5.)

Moreover, the first Chern class of $\mathcal{L}$ is $c_1(\mathcal{L})=-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\Omega,$ and the degree of the line bundle is $$\deg(\mathcal{L})=\int_Xc_1(\mathcal{L}).$$ 
In particular, degree nonzero implies $c_1(\mathcal{L})$ (and therefore the curvature form) is nonzero.

Comment: Thank you! I was confused on the dimensionality requirement by the phrasing in the section of Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups on holomorphic connections which said that "flatness is automatic in dimension 1". I suppose this is only for the non-compact case as Steve hinted at in his comment.

Comment: @DanielSantiago Sorry, I just realized that holomorphic connection is different from the $C^{\infty}$-connection. The answer that I gave is $C^{\infty}$ version which has curvature form of type $(1,1)$ (not a holomorphic 2-form). Your reference is right about dimension one, since $\Omega_X^2$ is always zero. Could you let me know which reference you are reading from? Also, please unaccept this answer. I will fix it soon.

Comment: The reference I've been reading from is the book "Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups" by Tamas Szamuely. It goes over Riemann Surfaces and Integrable Holomorphic Connections briefly for the purpose of describing the Riemann-Hilbert Correspondence but isn't that in depth for general results of the field. I also have "Riemann Surfaces" by Farkas and Kra.

Comment: @DanielSantiago Thanks! I will have to work on something else now. Hopefully, I will get back to this problem on Friday.

Comment: Dear @DanielSantiago, here is what I have so far. First, existence of holomorphic connection is a stong condition put on a holomorphic vector bundle $E\to X$, for instance, this will imply $c_i(E)=0$ for all $i>0$ (Ex 4.4.12 in Huybrechets' Complex Geometry). Moreover, if $\nabla$ is a holomorphic connection, then $D=\nabla+\bar{\partial}_E$ is a $C^{\infty}$-connection, and the (1,1)-part of its curvature tensor $R^{1,1}_{D}$ is the _zero_ class in $H^{1,1}(X,End(E))$ (prop. 4.5 in [this paper](https://www.insa.nic.in/writereaddata/UpLoadedFiles/IJPAM/20014c96_3.pdf)).(continued)

Comment: And asking for $\nabla$ being flat is the same as asking $D$ being flat. But the condition above does not necessarily means the curvature tensor itself being zero. So all I want to say is asking for $\nabla$ being flat is an extra strong assuption and I think there should be "generically" many nonflat connection for $\dim X\ge 2$, althogh I cannot even come up with one. If you are eager to know the answer, I suggest you to post this question on MO.

Comment: Thank you! You have been extremely helpful, I wish I could upvote more than once! I'll cross-post this to MO and see what I get, but you have done most of it yourself.